# How can I boot into a live stick out of a running linux?

Tags: linux, efi, liveusb

I have problem that might be very rare. I want to boot into a live stick out of a running linux (Unbuntu in my case). Doing it the normal way, like rebooting and choosing the stick in the boot options menu is not an option. It has to be right out of the running OS.

The purpose of this is to outsmart a broken EFI, that cannot just be repaired.
But however I have to boot the stick, on this hardware.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks and Best Regards

Comment: What do you mean by a "broken EFI"? What have you tried to enter BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: installing kvm or similar would allow you to boot it concurrently.  The only issue is that the 2 units are isolated from each other.  Some amount of pass through can be configured, but I don't know if its enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

At the point in time, when the boot drive is decided, there is no OS running - so the OS has no possibility to decide, which OS will be booted next.

What you can try is to get the boot loader (GRUB2) prompt for your Ubuntu and manually enter the sequence of commands needed to boot from the USB stick - this is quite an effort and not universal recipe exists (as it is dependant on your configuration), but it is doable.

Comment: Right, I forgot that I can simply solve this out with grub. This will do the job. I found out that with grub2, I can simply tell grub to directly boot into an ISO on the on the hard drive, so I do not even need the stick. Long ago that I did these kinds of things. Thx